# Is there a way to make Alexa's ia_archiver slow down its crawling of my website?

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, cache, internet-archive

[Alexa's ia_archiver bot](http://www.botopedia.org/user-agent-list/search-bots/alexa-crawler) is the [main contributor](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/690/21219) to the Internet Archive's "Wayback Machine" web collection, and there are advantages to having my website included in that collection. There are other robots that do other useful things too.

What's a quick and easy way to make ia_archiver crawl my website more slowly, in order to put less load on the server? I haven't tested [the Crawl-delay directive](http://enwp.org/Robots_exclusion_standard#Crawl-delay_directive): if you have, and it works, please tell me so. If it doesn't work, please leave a comment. If you've never tested Crawl-delay, then instead please recommend some other solution that takes fifteen minutes or less to implement. Maybe there exists some easy-to-implement [software-based solution](http://www.google.com/search?q=apache+throttle) which will let me throttle too-rapid hits from ia_archiver?

Please assume my website is running on Apache 2.4.3 on Debian Linux 6.0.6 on a dedicated server which I administer.

Comment: Related: ["Control over the Internet Archive besides just 'Disallow /'?"](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/680/control-over-the-internet-archive-besides-just-disallow)

Comment: Why haven't you tested the Crawl-delay directive? It's dead simple to implement and Alexa is a responsible company and known to honor robots.txt. I'd be astonished if they didn't honor the crawl-delay directive.

Comment: @Kris:  I actually asked my question to get information for another webmaster:  he currently blocks ia_archiver from his massive and useful site.  My website is composed of just one solitary webpage (/index.html), so I can't really test Crawl-delay.  :)  But anyway, the Crawl-delay directive has never been part of the official Robot Exclusion Standard.  Even though ia_archiver follows the entire standard, it still might ignore Crawl-delay.

Comment: How fast is too fast? I've never seen ia_archiver crawl faster than one page every few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Crawling for the Internet Archive is done both by Alex and by the Internet Archive's own crawlers. Support for the Crawl-Delay directive in the robots.txt file is vairly hap-hazard between the two due to the directive not being part of the official robots.txt standard. In addition the way both companies treat the Crawl-Delay directive when they do accept it seems to change over time in my experience. I have tried doing this in the past and have found that sometimes the Crawl-Delay directive has been respected by both, other times only one has respected it, and yet some other times neither has, and there doesn't seem to be a pattern to when it is respected or not. The only thing I can suggest that will definitely work is to add a `disallow` directive for both the Alexa crawler and the ia_crawler.